# Testing error message content for multiple languages

Tags: c#, unit-testing, design-patterns

I'm writing negative tests for checking content of error message shown to the user. There are two languages in app: english and german. The test works but the code for checking each language looks like this:

```cs
//Check if modal dialog with error message is shown
string currentLanguage = loginPage.currentLanguage.Text;
string modalMessage = loginPage.errorMsgModalDialogTitle.Text;

try
{
    Assert.True(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(modalMessage));
    test.Log(Status.Pass, "Office365 login has failed and modal dialog was shown to user!");
    test.Log(Status.Info, "Checking modal dialog error message...");

    switch (currentLanguage)
    {
        //Current language is english
        case "German":
            try
            {
                Assert.AreEqual(modalMessage, "User does not exist!");
                test.Log(Status.Pass, "Modal dialog message title verified!  Message title: '" + modalMessage + "'");
            }
            catch(AssertionException)
            {
                test.Log(Status.Fail, "Modal dialog did not contain message title: '" + modalMessage + "'");
            }
            break;

        //Current language is german
        case "English":
            try
            {
                Assert.AreEqual(modalMessage, "Benutzer existiert nicht!");
                test.Log(Status.Pass, "Modal dialog message title and text verified!  Message title: '" + modalMessage + "'");
            }
            catch (AssertionException)
            {
                test.Log(Status.Fail, "Modal dialog did not contain message title: '" + modalMessage + "'");
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

As you can see, the code to check the title of modal dialog in both languages is kinda too big and there will be negative tests with even more error messages to check in both languages.

Is there a way to somehow refractor this code and make it simpler or cleaner? Could I create some helper method that just takes current language as parameter, message and expected message and just return true or false?

Comment: Testing the language is not really relevant. However, specifying some "verified" resource files for the test should work. If the case is that you make sure somebody haven't broken the language file. You'll have to manage double the files.

Answer (score 0):

Here, you should follow below approach

1. Keep multiple resource files for different languages having the assertion data, e.g., ModuleUnitTestAssertions.en.resx, ModuleUnitTestAssertions.de.resx, etc.
2. Based on current language(the set in test Setup method), select your resource file
3. Replace your assertion strings with values from the resx files

Using above approach, you will not need any switch case, and it will work for all languages without any code changes.